# Python program.py vs Pasting code not passing basic installed authentication

Tags: python, html, authentication, cmd, passwords

I am wanting to open a webpage of a internal webpage for a reporting tool called statseeker, that stores images that are generated from a report ran when a URL is opened. So far I am at this:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import lxml, lxml.html



ID = '4050'

PorS = '1'

base_link = 'http://statseeker/cgi/nim-report?rid=42237&command=Graph&mode=ping&list=jc-'

dash = '-'

end_link =  '&tfc_fav=range+%3D+start_of_today+-+1d+to+now%3B&year=&month=&day=&hour=&minute=&duration=&wday_from=&wday_to=&time_from=&time_to=&tz=America%2FChicago&tfc=range+%3D+start_of_today+-+1d+to+now%3B&rtype=Delay&graph_type=Filled&db_type=Average&x_step=1&interval=60&y_height=100&y_gridlines=5&y_max=&y_max_power=1&x_gridlines=on&legend=on'


urlauth = base_link + ID + dash + tPorS + end_link

print urlauth

realm = 'statseeker'
username = 'username'
password = '*******'
auth_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
auth_handler.add_password(realm, urlauth, username, password)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
data = opener.open(urlauth).read()

html = lxml.html.fromstring(data)
imgs = html.cssselect('img.graph')
for x in imgs:
   y = 'http://statseeker%s' % (x.attrib['src'])
   urllib.urlretrieve(y, 'test.jpg')
   print 'http://statseeker%s' % (x.attrib['src'])
   with open('statseeker.html', 'a') as f:
    f.write(y)
```

When I run this manually in python by copy and paste the code executes fine.

When I save this as `grab.py` and run it via CMD `python grab.py` It asks me to login again at line `urllib.urlretrieve(y, 'test.jpg')`

So I am deducing that this for some reason is not passing it's authentication from

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

But I do not know why.

Comment: Also I have already tride using `urllib2.urlretrieve(y, 'test.jpg')`

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlretrieve'`

Comment: What interpreter python version do you run this in, and what python version is used when you run `grab.py`?

Comment: Python 2.7.8 for both as it's the only one installed.

Comment: I'm confused what your `for` loop is doing? From what I can tell you build a url, retrieve the file and save it as `test.jpg` (for every iteration), and then after reporting the url you append the url to the file statseeker.html.  If this is the intended, why not just skip the `urlrequest` part and just append the url's to the file?

Comment: The 'for' loop is creating the URL's of the images that lie on the page. It grabs all urls and puts them into variable `y`. From that oint I try to somehow pull y using `urllib.urlretrieve(y, 'test.jpg')`